# How to programmatically turn torch-flash light on

Tags: android

I am using LG Optimus 3D model, I am able to turn on the torch light when I switch the camera to video recording mode. In normal capture mode, I am only able to turn on flash light.

I have tried several way by adding different parameters into the Camera object, but none of them work. My code is as below:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_flash_light);



    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

    if (! pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Your phone does not have flash light support.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }

    camera = Camera.open(); 
    cParameters = camera.getParameters();



    cParameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
camera.setParameters(cParameters);

}
```

No point I cannot turn it on programmatically, I have checked as below to ensure my phone support torch mode, in fact, I am really able to turn on for my device.

```
List<String> abc = cParameters.getSupportedFlashModes();

        for (String a : abc){
            Log.d("mode: ", a);
}
```

Please help, anyway to do that?
* The firmware is 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the following

```
 context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
```

to see if a flash is available or not. It will will return true or false.

More here on how to actually implement the code.

[How to turn on the Android Flashlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005001/android-lg-revolution-flashlight)

[Use camera flashlight in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503480/use-camera-flashlight-in-android?lq=1)

[How to turn on camera flash light programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068803/how-turn-on-only-camera-flash-light-programmatically-in-android)